# Prevent link from changing when mouse button is released

Tags: css

I have an  element like:

```
<a id='a_id' class='a_class'>Next</a>
```

The element shows in green, underlined.

When I hover over the element, it changes to a lighter green, not underlined (which is fine).

When I click, during the mouse button down nothing changes.

When I release the mouse button, the element changes briefly showing a green background and goes back to lighter green, not underlined.

How can I change the CSS to prevent the change when I release the mouse button?

I tried the following CSS:

```
.a_class {
    cursor:pointer;
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#fff;
}
```

Thanks.

**UPDATE #1 - using .a_class:active**

I added the following CSS:

```
.a_class:active {
    outline:none;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:#fff;
    color:red;
}
```

I added the color:red to confirm the CSS was being applied.

When I press down the mouse button, the text color changes to red. And when I release the mouse button, the background flashes in green for a second.

Any other suggestion?

Thanks.

**UPDATE #2 - adding full CSS of the link**

When I inspect the page with firebug the element has the following CSS:

```
.a_class {
  background:#FFFFFF;
  cursor:pointer;
  outline:none;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a {
  color:#24890D;
  text-decoration:none; <- crossed out
}

.entry-content a, .entry-summary a, .page-content a, .comment-content a {
  text-decoration:underline; <- crossed out
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
  border:0;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:100%;
  font-style:inherit;
  font-weight:inherit;
  margin:0;
  outline:0; <- crossed out
  padding:0;
  vertical-align:baseline;
}
```

Comment: .a_class:active maybe ?

Comment: full CSS of the link?

Comment: @RafH I tried .a_class:active and it didn't work. I updated the question with the attempt. any other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @sebastianbrosch I updated the question with the css I get when I inspect the element with firebug. Thanks.

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't show that behavior—at least in my browser. What browser are you using?

Comment: @ralph.m I am using Chrome Version 50.0.2661.75 m

Comment: e too. So there's something missing from your code. Make sure to create a demo that shows the behavior. Otherwise the problem remains a mystery.

Comment: Same problem with Firefox 43.0.4 and Explorer 11.0.30